# communication failure between availability zones in one region in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, high-availability

Is there a possibility for communication failure between availability zones in one region in AWS(assuming both AZs are up but only network communication failure)? If there is communication failure, is it considered as AWS region failure?

Answer (score 0):

Anything can fail, but I suspect AWS have redundant links between their availability zones. If you want to know how AWS classify failures you'd best ask them.

What are you trying to solve / achieve?

Comment: I have two EC2 instances(Active/Passive), one in its own AZ. When communication between AZs is down, both EC2 instances become active(split-brain). So I was trying to see how this split brain could be solved without using third tie breaker AZ.

Comment: It's very rare for inter-AZ communications to go down. In AWS you're generally better off trying to rearchitect for active-active, or keep shared state in a multi-AZ RDS database. If you want help with that best ask a new question.